# How do I level up my Delusion?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In the Witcher 3: The Wild Hunt, how do I level up delusion so I can influence people's decisions while speaking to them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is simply the first upgrade of the Axii skill in the Signs category. You need to put between one or three points into this skill, depending on how hard the individual check in the dialogue is.

[image]

You also need to put the skill into a slot on the right side of that screen, like with all the other skills.